# Change properties in a class using a form from a different class

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a number of propertied in a class that creates a pdf document that need to be set before the pdf is created.  This class is named generatePDF. I would like be able to change the properties using a form and persist the properties.

INotifyPropertyChanged was implemented in the generatePDF class.  I used the Data Source Configuration Wizard (Open DataSources vertical tab on the far right side of the screen , click the upper left icon to add a Data source) to bind the GeneratePDF class.  Now in the Datasources windows I can see all the properties and can easily drag them onto a configuration form.

I have a method in the generatePDF class that puts initial values into the properties.  I ran this method before showing the configuration form.

When the configuration form is shown the textboxes that I would expect to be filled with the initial values are blank.  When I enter a value that should change the property in my GeneratePDF instance, the property is not changed.  In addition, there is control automatically added to the configuration form that apparently allows the user to step through different instances of the GeneratePDF class -- like rows in a database table.  The configuration form doesn't appear to be bound to the single instance of the GeneratePDF class.

I tried to change the GeneratePDF and all the properties and methods of the  to static, but when that was completed and error "... can't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on a static class..." was shown.

I'm guessing I'm not the first one to experience this problem but I was unable to state my question clearly enough so that a google search would find an answer or a tutorial.

I'd appreciate help binding a specific instance of a class to a configuration form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've been working on this all day, and I think I've found a solution.

When I added the project data source GeneratePDF, a ??what does microsoft call this?? 'GeneratePDFBindingSource' was added to the project.  I went ahead and drug all the properties from this class onto a configuration form.

I modified the constructor of the configuration form to the the instance of GeneratePDF as a paramter.

The constructor is also modified.  After Initialize Component runs, the configuration form binding source is just a 'typeOf' GeneratePDF.  The DataSource property of GeneratePDFBindingSource was updated to point to the instance which I just passed in.

However, when the form was displayed the values STILL were showing blanks.  I looked at the system generated code for the configuration and noticed that there was an EndEdit() method that could be called when changes were completed.  Adding this to the constructor and... it worked!

So below are the few simple lines of finished code.  I'm posting this answer in case others happen upon this question, or if I forget how to do this at some time in the future and need a reference.

```
namespace com.myCompany.myApp
{
    public partial class frm_Configuration : Form
    {
        public frm_Configuration(GeneratePDF generatePdf)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GeneratePDFBindingSource.DataSource = generatePdf;
            GeneratePDFBindingSource.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```